Hide download link as soon as the download starts
Question:
What do I have to do to hide a download link as soon as the download starts?
Problem:
The difficulty or problem for me here is that a password is sent with the user request. If the password is correct, the download starts. If the password is incorrect, the download is redirected to the same page.
Blade / Frontend
<form action="/download/{{ $data->uuid }}" method="POST" class="download-with-pw">
  @csrf
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>

Controller / Backend
...
if ($request->input('password') === $file->password) {
  return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::download($path);
}


It's unclear why that problem means that you have to hide the download link? (By "link", do you mean the html form you've shown us?). Surely if the password is wrong the user can have  a chance to try it again

@ADyson If you download without a password check, I would use a click eventListener with JS to hide the form and make the success message visible. But due to the possibility that the password can be entered incorrectly, I cannot use this option. Unless I could wait with Javascript until the download stream from the server starts. That would be the trigger. Is this possible?

"If the password is incorrect, the download is redirected to the same page." - so where is the problem then? If you hide the link on the current page using JS, and then there is an actual redirect, so that the page will load anew - then your link would automatically be visible again in this newly loaded page, no?

It sounds like a fairly straightforward workflow - the form posts back to the server, then PHP checks the password. If the password is ok, initiate the download. If it's not, return an error message so the user can enter the password again. It's not clear why you need to hide the form in any case?

@ADyson From a UX perspective, I would like to hide it. Because when the download starts and the form with the password and submit button is still visible, it feels wrong. Don't you think so?

It's a matter of opinion I guess. But anyway I expect you should just hide it by hanlding the "submit" event of the form using JS. It should run before the submission occurs. Then rather than a "success" message, just put a "your download will start shortly" message, or something like that - that's pretty common on download sites. Then if it turns out there's an error, the server will redirect the browser back to a suitable point, which presumably will show the form again anyway.

Another option is to redesign it so the download happens via JS/AJAX, I guess

@ADyson I first had it as a Javascript solution. The handling would not be a problem. But the problem was that JS is not a solution for large files. Pushing 500MB or more into a JS blob is semi-optimal. Hence the "classic" way with the attempt to get a little UX feeling :-) But your solution in the comment is completely correct and that's how I'll do it. Thank you. If you want to write an answer I would accept it. Regards

I expect you should just hide it by handling the "submit" event of the form using JS. It should run before the submission occurs.
Rather than a "success" message, just put a "your download will start shortly" message, or something like that - that's pretty common on download sites.
Then if it turns out there's an error, the server will redirect the browser back to a suitable point, which presumably will show the form again anyway.

To hide the download link once the download has started you can use javascipt to detect form submission and immediately hide the link

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
